# how to make a table in mysql with these data?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database like this,

```
$patients = array();
$patients[0] = array(

  'first_name' => 'john' ,

  'last_name' => 'doe' ,

  'diseases' => array ( 'Mood disorders' , 'Thyroid Cancer' , 'Migraine' ),

  'medication' => array (
                    'pills' => array ( 'amoxicillin' , 'Vicodin' ) , 
                    'syrups' => array ( 'Zantac' , 'Invirase' ) , 
                    'surgeries' => array ( 'Urinary' , 'Ears' , 'Endocrine' )
                  )

);
```

and I echo these out different places for example
somewhere I echo all Medication and someplace else I just echo pills.

Now if I make this a table in mysql how can I put the inner data? 
If I make a column Medication How should I put `pills` and `surgeries` inside it?

Comment: you can put in as json format

Comment: I'm sorry bur you're basically asking us to teach you how to design a database... Which is a very broad topic!

Comment: Use relations. Read some tutorial about relational databases.

Comment: can't you at least tell me If it is or isn't possible in mysql at all?

Comment: Is it unprofessional to just use arrays instead anyway?

Comment: you know in the top of every page include the array.php file

Comment: Arrays are not database :)

Answer (score -1):

you can used this with single table with json_encode and json_decode

```
<?php
$patients = array();
$patients[0] = array(

  'first_name' => 'john' ,

  'last_name' => 'doe' ,

  'diseases' => array ( 'Mood disorders' , 'Thyroid Cancer' , 'Migraine' ),

  'medication' => array (
                    'pills' => array ( 'amoxicillin' , 'Vicodin' ) , 
                    'syrups' => array ( 'Zantac' , 'Invirase' ) , 
                    'surgeries' => array ( 'Urinary' , 'Ears' , 'Endocrine' )
                  )

);

$encode = json_encode($patients);

echo $encode;

// Output 

//[{"first_name":"john","last_name":"doe","diseases":["Mood disorders","Thyroid Cancer","Migraine"],"medication":{"pills":["amoxicillin","Vicodin"],"syrups":["Zantac","Invirase"],"surgeries":["Urinary","Ears","Endocrine"]}}]
// sore above string in table


$decode = json_decode($encode, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($decode);
echo "</pre>";

//output

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => john
            [last_name] => doe
            [diseases] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mood disorders
                    [1] => Thyroid Cancer
                    [2] => Migraine
                )

            [medication] => Array
                (
                    [pills] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => amoxicillin
                            [1] => Vicodin
                        )

                    [syrups] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Zantac
                            [1] => Invirase
                        )

                    [surgeries] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Urinary
                            [1] => Ears
                            [2] => Endocrine
                        )

                )

        )

)
</pre>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man but I don't understand something here, Can I put my DATA to patients.json and for example print_r($patients)?

Comment: I meant to a patients.json file.